# Prob question on games

Tags: probability

I am playing in a racquetball tournament, and I am up against a player I have
watched but never played before. I consider three possibilities for my prior model: we are
equally talented, and each of us is equally likely to win each game; I am slightly better,
and therefore I win each game independently with probability 0.6; or he is slightly better,
and thus he wins each game independently with a probability 0.6. Before we play, I think
that each of the three possibilities is equally likely.
In our match we play until one player wins three games. I win the second game, but
he wins the first, third, and fourth. After this match, in my posterior model, with what
probability should I believe that my opponent is slightly better than I am?

I am getting an answer of 17/30.  Can someone verify if it is correct? Thanks a lot

Comment: How did you get 17/30?

Comment: It is long answer which I did it in EXCEL.  I just need someone to let me know if they solved the problem and what their answer is.  If you want I can email my EXCEL sheet.

Comment: Steps to follow: What is the probability of  $3:1$ wins for a better, an equally talented, a worse player? Then use Bayes

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I found the prior probability in a long way. They are as you mentioned, $\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}$.  Is there a short trick to finding it out.  And you know as well,that I complicate things.  Wondering if you could suggest something?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, is the answer provided by the responder correct?.  I would appreciate if you could vet the answer.  I believe he is correct but would want someone like you to say it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p$ denote your a priori probability of winning a game .The pmf of $p$ is $$\mathbb{P}(p=\alpha) = 1/3$$ for $\alpha \in \lbrace 0.4, 0.5, 0.6 \rbrace$. Then by Bayes'
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(p=\alpha \mid \text{LWLL}) &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(\text{LWLL} \mid p = \alpha)\mathbb P (p  =\alpha)}{\mathbb P (\text{LWLL})}\\
&= \frac{(1-\alpha)^3\alpha \frac{1}{3} }{\sum_\alpha \mathbb P (\text{LWLL} \mid p = \alpha ) \mathbb P(p=\alpha)}\\
&= \frac{(1-\alpha)^3\alpha}{0.1873}
\end{align}
$$
For $\alpha = 0.4$ this becomes approximately $0.46$.

Comment: how did you get the pmf $P(p=\alpha) = \frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: @satishramanathan since each case is equally likely and there are three cases

Comment: Where are you finding the prori probability of one winning on all three cases when your opponent is better, equally talented, and worse,.  In other words, where are you using the fact that the probability of your opponent winning the game is 0.6 other than the time when you calculate the P(LWLL)?

Comment: well, that is denoted by $\mathbb P (\text{LWLL} \mid p = \alpha)$. $\alpha$ is your probability of winning, his is $(1-\alpha)$. So the case you are interested in is substituted as $\alpha = 0.4$ at the end.

Comment: Priori probability of you winning the tournament should not have any information of the event of winning the match (LWLL).  Don't you think, it is more complicated of finding one winning in each possibility (of course each of one of them are equally likely of a scenario, not winning though). I thought you should calculate the priori probability of winning the tournament under the condition that each player needs to win three games first to be a winner.  I have a habit of overcomplicating things. Just clarify this, please

Comment: The probability I calculated gives you the probability of him being better than you, given the result of the match (i.e. sequence LWLL). I don't know what you mean when you bring the whole tournament into the problem.

Comment: I should have said match, not tournament, Let us define match as winning three games first.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a tree diagram.

Event you've witnessed is LWLL. What is the probability of this under each case?

Work your way backwards through tree diagram to calculate posterior probabilities.

Now calculate the expected probability of your friend winning a random game under posterior model.